# inheriting from forms/controls and writing modular code

Tags: c#, winforms, refactoring

I've written a couple simple GUI applications but all of the logic is basically written in the default Form1 class that I'm given.

So I thought maybe I'll rewrite the GUI logic into their own classes. For example, a class for the FileOpenDialog, another class for a ListView, and so on. That way my Form1 class doesn't have too many unnecessary methods and is just there for handling some basic stuff, possibly not a lot after the other GUI methods have been moved around.

Wrote something like this as a first attempt to get somewhere

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class OpenFileDialog1 : OpenFileDialog
    {
    }
}
```

But then VS tells me I can't derive from a sealed type.

I haven't tried it with the other classes, but I'll probably run into the same issue at some point. Am I not inheriting it correctly? Or do I have to use some sort of workarounds to separate each GUI element into their own classes?

Maybe this is not a good approach?

Comment: You cannot inherit from sealed classes, and chances are you don't want to do what you think you're doing?  You would extend a class to improve/modify it's functionality.  It sounds to me like you want to do partial classes on your form.

Comment: So I would just make another form class and have all of my file opening logic there? I would like to just say "ok, so the user wants to open a file. I don't care how you do it just prompt him somehow and return something from the user". I might substitute a different set of methods for file opening, but my main form class shouldn't know anything about it.

Comment: I don't really understand your quest, but it sounds like you need to use some factory classes to satisfy your desire.  I'll clarify in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your clarifying comments, it sounds like you either want some utility classes or factory classes.  Perhaps something like below:

```
public interface IFileOpener
{
    public bool PresentFileOpenDialogToUser();
    public string RequestedFilePath { get; }
}

public class DefaultFileOpener : IFileOpener
{
    private string filePath = default(string);

    public bool PresentFileOpenDialogToUser()
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        DialogResult dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            this.filePath = default(string);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.filePath = ofd.FileName;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public string RequestedFilePath
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.filePath;
        }
    }
}

public class FileOpenerFactory
{
    public static IFileOpener CreateFileOpener()
    {
        return new DefaultFileOpener();
    }
}
```

And in your form:

```
    private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IFileOpener opener = FileOpenerFactory.CreateFileOpener();
        if (opener.PresentFileOpenDialogToUser())
        {
            //do something with opener.RequestedFilePath;
        }
    }
```

You could even do something with a partial class so in your main form you have something like

```
    private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.OpenMyFile();
    }
```

and in your partial class you have:

```
public partial class Form1
{
    private void OpenMyFile()
    {
        IFileOpener opener = FileOpenerFactory.CreateFileOpener();
        if (opener.PresentFileOpenDialogToUser())
        {
            //do something with opener.RequestedFilePath;
        }
    }
}
```

Many times its very useful to use partial classes as implementations of interfaces or focused functionality.

Comment: Yes, factory pattern was what I was looking for (name didn't come to me). From the code you've written, my understanding of the main form is that it is like some "driver" of sorts that handles all events and requests?

Comment: Correct, and as I tried to allude to you could even split that up into partial classes so one "partial" section is just initialization, one would be for event handling, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It *is* a good approach. But don't inherit from `OpenFileDialog`. Just create a simple class and put the stuff there.

Something like this (just as an idea):

```
class FileDialogStuff
{
    static OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    public static string GetFile()
    {
        DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
        //Do stuff
        return dialog.FileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: @inspiro  So suppose I defined a class called "MyFileOpenPrompt", and it made calls to the OpenFileDialog. I would probably like to avoid instantiating an instance of MyFileOpenPrompt because I only defined it to make my code cleaner. Instead I want to say "MyFileOpenPrompt.prompt_user()". Are static methods the only way to achieve this?

Comment: See my edit (written before I saw your comment). What's wrong with static methods? Don't make the whole class static - It doesn't help anyway (Except to prevent you from accidentally creating non-static stuff.)

Comment: that works nicely, although it looks like I have to define the `FileDialogStuff_FileOK` method inside my Form1 class. Is there a way to move that into this new class as well?

Comment: @Keikoku What do you mean? What is that method, and why can't it be in the new class? Do you mean - how to use it? - `string filePath = FileDialogStuff.GetFile();`

Comment: Not sure what it is, but when I double-click the OpenFileDialog in designer view, it is automatically created in my Form1 class. VS seems to want this method defined before I can actually display the dialog. EDIT: oh it's an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

As per the c# specification, a sealed class can not be inherited to the another class. you have to initiated directly.

if OpenFileDialog is the sealed class, then you can not inherit it.